# What is the significance of the last two digits of a 2's complement number being 00?

Tags: binary

What is the significance of the last two digits of a 2's complement number being 00?

The first part of this question is what is the significance of the last digit being 0?  I said  that the digit will be an even number.  I don't know what the significance of the last two being 00 is.  Can someone give me some help so I can find the answer?  Does it just mean that it will end up having two zeros at the end of the number??

Answer (score 1):

It means the digit will be divisible by 4.